# Meteor.js/javascript iPhone tap input lag

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm not sure this is a Meteor.js specific question, but here goes:

I've created a demo at http://numbersdemo.meteor.com/. If you try the demo in a desktop browser (I've only tried it in Chrome on Mac) it runs fine, the input from the buttons is instantly displayed in the results-thing. **But if you try it on an iPhone, it's not quite as instant. And that's what I need!**

Is it possible?

Is it a Meteor.js problem or just javascript/HTML in mobile Safari?

Below is all the .js for the app. And as you can see there are no DB connections at all going on, just a Session, so the DB is not the problem.

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {

  Meteor.startup(function () {
    Session.set('buttonsResult', 0);
  });

  Template.numbersThing.result = function () {
    return Session.get('buttonsResult');
  };

  Template.numbersThing.events({
    'mousedown .button' : function (event) {
      var prevInput = Session.get('buttonsResult'),
      newInput = prevInput + '' + $(event.currentTarget).text();
      Session.set('buttonsResult', newInput);
    },
    'mousedown .reset' : function () {
      Session.set('buttonsResult', 0);
    }
  });

}

if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.startup(function () {

  });
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using an event like touchstart instead of mousedown?

Comment: Rahul: you are a genius. http://numbersdemo2.meteor.com/ (don't work in desktop browsers now though, but is instant on iPhone!)

(Also: can I mark your answer as the "correct" on in some way? SO-n00b right here!)

Comment: I posted the comment as an answer, so you can accept that :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried using an event like touchstart instead of mousedown?

Answer (score 1):

Try using [**FastClick**](https://github.com/ftlabs/fastclick), which removes the 300ms delay time when tapping a link.